url-template package is throwing error ERR_REQUIRE_ESM after build with webpack 5 upgrade, even with module set to commonjs
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, I'm not sure how to even phrase the question properly - but essentially I have been tasked with an upgrade from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5 and it has been quite an ordeal to bring up all of the package dependencies and make things play nicely with each other. Looking for any tips or help with the configuration setup and the following issue.  I will gladly accept any advice on formatting the question better or providing more info - thanks for taking time out of your day to help.
I am using import { parseTemplate } from 'url-template'; in actions.js file.
npm run build works properly, but npm run start fails with the following:
error:  /code/build/components/app/actions.js:13
const url_template_1 = require("url-template"); Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
webpack.config.js
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WebpackManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin').WebpackManifestPlugin;
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin").CleanWebpackPlugin;
const hashDigest = 'hex'
const hashDigestLength = 20
const hashFunction = 'sha384'
const config = require('./src/config/index.js');
const topdir = __dirname;

const baseConfig =
{
  context: path.resolve(topdir),
  entry: {
    app: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'client', 'index.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'sass', 'index.scss')
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.cjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    fallback: { "url": false },
    fullySpecified: false,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
    hashDigest,
    hashDigestLength,
    hashFunction,
    publicPath: config.ASSET_PATH,
    // library: {
    //   type: 'module'
    // }
  },
  module:{
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // include: filename => {
        //   return /node_modules\/url-template/.test(filename)
        // },
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!escape-string-regexp|nanoid|postcss|sanitize-html\/)/,
        use:
          [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader'
              , options:
              {
                cacheDirectory: true
                , babelrc: false
                , compact: false
                , presets:
                  [
                    ['@babel/preset-env'
                      , {
                        modules: false,
                        targets:
                        {
                          browsers: [
                            "last 2 chrome versions",
                            "last 2 edge versions",
                            "last 2 firefox versions",
                            "last 2 safari versions",
                            "ie >= 11"
                          ]
                        },
                        useBuiltIns: "entry",
                        corejs: { version: '3.37', proposals: true }
                      }
                    ]
                    , '@babel/preset-typescript'
                    , '@babel/preset-react'
                  ]
                , plugins:
                  [
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
                    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                    '@loadable/babel-plugin',
                    [
                      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
                      { legacy: true }
                    ],
                    [
                      '@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties'
                    ],
                  ],
                  assumptions: {
                    setPublicClassFields: true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
      },
      { test: /\.([cm]?ts|tsx)$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'transpiled', 'client'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'sass')
        ],
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ["autoprefixer"],
              }
            }
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        type: 'asset/resource',
        // options: {
        //   limit: 10 * 1024
        // }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.eot$/, /\.ttf$/, /\.svg$/, /\.woff$/, /\.woff2$/],
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[name][ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        client: {
          test: /[\\/]src\/client[\\/]/,
          name: 'client',
          chunks: 'all'
        },
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendor",
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
      swSrc: "./src/components/service-worker/src-sw.js",
      swDest: "service-worker.js",
      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
      exclude: [
        /\.map$/,
        /manifest$/,
        /\.htaccess$/,
        /service-worker\.js$/,
        /sw\.js$/,
      ],
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].[chunkHash].css', chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkHash].css' }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({ fileName: 'inventory.json', publicPath: '' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      {
        patterns: [
          { from: "./src/components/service-worker/manifest.json", to: "." },
        ],
      }
    ),
  ],
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /\.sw.$/
  },
  // experiments: {
  //   outputModule: true
  // }
}

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  let config
  if (argv.mode !== 'production' && !(env && env.prod)) {
    config = {
      ...baseConfig,
      mode: 'development',
      // devServer: {
      //   hot: true,
      //   // static: {
      //   //   directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'assets'),
      //   //   publicPath: '/public/assets/',
      //   // },
      // },
      devtool: 'eval-source-map',
      plugins: [
        ...baseConfig.plugins,
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        // new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
      ],
    }
  } else {
    config = {
      ...baseConfig,
      mode: 'production',
      devtool: 'source-map',
      optimization: {
        ...baseConfig.optimization,
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          ...baseConfig.optimization.minimizer,
          new TerserPlugin()
        ]
      }
    }
  }

  return config
}

tsconfig.json
{
     "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": "./",
       "declaration": true,
       "strict": true,
       "module": "commonjs",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "target": "es6",
       "jsx": "react",
       "alwaysStrict": true,
       "sourceMap": false,
       "outDir": "./build",
       "rootDirs": [
         "src"
       ],
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "allowJs": true,
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "lib": [
         "dom",
         "es2015",
         "es5",
         "es6",
         "esnext.asynciterable",
         "es2018.promise",
         "es2019"
       ],
       "typeRoots": [
         "./@types",
         "node_modules/@types"
       ]
     },
     "include": [
       "src/**/*.ts",
       "src/**/*.tsx",
       "./@types"
     ],
     "exclude": [
       "node_modules"
     ]
}

package.json (snippet)
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.3.14",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.16"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf public build",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test npm run tsc && mocha 'build/**/*.test.js'",
    "build": "cross-env npm run build:tsc && cross-env npm run build:webpack",
    "build:tsc": "tsc",
    "build:webpack": "webpack --mode production",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tscw": "tsc -w",
    "start": "rimraf public && cross-env node -r dotenv/config build/server/index.js dotenv_config_path=config/.env",
    "start:dev": "DEBUG=TODO:* cross-env node -r dotenv/config build/server/index.js dotenv_config_path=config/.env",
    "start:restart": "npm run tsc && npm run start",
    "start:dev:restart": "npm run tsc && npm run start:dev"
  },
}

